# VPN PPTP connection can't keep stable for more than 10 seconds [14.04 LTS]

Tags: 14.04, vpn, pptp

I'm trying to establish a VPN PPTP connection and I already done this, but the connection can't remain stable for more than 10 seconds. In the most of times the connection ends in one or two seconds.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.